# table - textwidth

Tags: tables

How to set table on the whole width of table. I thought with `\textwidth`. I would like a table with width `\textwidth`, 3 cols, `ccl` alignment of cols

and width of cols about:

- first col `0,25\textwidth`,
- second `0,25\textwidth`
- and third `0,5\textwidth`.

Where is a mistake please?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[a-2u]{pdfx}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{icomma}         
\usepackage{booktabs}             
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}\small
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X X X }

Kanál   &Označení   &Veličina\\

1&  AS1&    Zeměpisná šířka 1 \\
17& g1& Exponent gravitačního ztemnění 1. složky\\


\Xhline{2\arrayrulewidth}


\end{tabularx}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You should use at least one `X` column type.

Comment: Thank you in this way I editted the code in question? It doesn't work.

Comment: Please be more specific as to what "It doesn't work" means in the current context. For what it's worth, if I add the instruction `\end{document}` in order to make your code compilable, the width of the line produced by `\Xhline` is exactly equal to `\textwidth`.

Comment: I added the picture to my question how the code look like - it is not textwidth

Comment: @Elisabeth, load `\usepackage{showframe}` and then you can see better the page area.

Comment: I loaded but I don't see what is the problem, why the third column in not nearby the right line

Comment: @Elisabeth: Do you want the contents of the third column to be right aligned as when using `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{c c >{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash}X }`?  If not, could you please add a sketch to further clarify the desired layout and alignment?

Comment: The width of the table is not related with the column alignment.

Comment: A quick solution for maybe single or 2 rows is to move the content by `\hfill Veličina` and `\hfill Zeměpisná šířka 1`.

Comment: I added picture, I would like to place column equally. The real table has not only two rows.

Comment: @Elisabeth Try with 3 X columns.

Comment: Thank you and how to do that the width is according to contain?

Comment: @Elisabeth, edit your post and tell us the layout of the table you wish to obtain: (1) table width; (2) number of cols; (3) alignment of **each** col; (4) width of **each** col.

Comment: I would like to (1) \textwidth ; (2) 3 cols (3) ccl alignment of cols (4) width of cols about: first col 0,25 textwidth, second 0,25 textwidth and third 0,5 textwidth

Comment: I editted the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
\small
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\hsize=0.25\hsize}X
                             >{\hsize=0.25\hsize}X
                             >{\hsize=0.50\hsize}X}
Kanál   &   Označení    &   Veličina            \\
1       &   AS1         &   Zeměpisná šířka 1   \\
17      &   g1          &   Exponent gravitačního ztemnění 1. složky\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I always thought the new widths still had to add up to the original value, because that's what it says in the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/tools/tabularx.pdf) (section 4.3). This would mean using `0.75\hsize`, `0.75\hsize` and `1.5\hsize` instead of your values. I wouldn't be able to tell you why though.

Comment: @Circumscribe, the sum of all column width should be integer. the best is if it is 1 (as in the above case 0.25+0.25+0.5=1). if it is bigger, for example 3 as you mentioned in your comment, will work in this simple example too, but not in all circumstances.

Comment: Interesting, thank you. Any idea why?

Comment: @Circumscribe, "why" is question for package author :-) . for integer "1" is clear, sum of columns' widths had to be equal to width of table.

Comment: I've looked into it: the "why" is essentially explained at the bottom of page 5 of the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/tools/tabularx.pdf). Using 1 instead of 3 here is slower (because everything in the table is typeset two additional times) and only works due to a mechanism designed for a corner case scenario where all cells of an `X` column are part of a `\multicolumn`.